# How to create a customized findBy on SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am a new SpringBoot developer. I would like to have a findByCountry instead of the regular findById on SpringBoot in my respository class:

CentralBankRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface CentralBankRepository extends MongoRepository<CentralBank, String> {
Optional<CentralBank> findByCountry(String country);
```

}

CentralBankController:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
public class CentralBankController {

@Autowired
CentralBankRepository centralBankRepository;

@GetMapping("/{country}")
public ResponseEntity<CentralBank> getCountry(@PathVariable("country") String country) {
return this.centralBankRepository.findByCountry(country).map(centralBank -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(centralBank))
    .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}
}
```

CentralBank:

```
import lombok.Data;

@Document(collection = "centralbank")
@Data
public class CentralBank {

@Id
private String mongoId;

private String country;
private int GDP;
private String GDPYoY;
private String GDPQoQ;
private String interestRate;
private String inflationRate;
private String joblessRate;
private String govBudget;
private String debtPerGDP;
private double currentAccount;
private double population;
}
```

When I go to http://localhost:8080/Canada, the message error is:

```
The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared.
The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range.
The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.
```

While I expect to receive this:

```
    {
    "Country": "Canada",
    "GDP": 1740,
    "GDP YoY": "-0.90%",
    "GDP QoQ": "-2.10%",
    "Interest rate": "0.25%",
    "Inflation rate": "-0.40%",
    "Jobless rate": "13.70%",
    "Gov. Budget": "-0.70%",
    "Debt/GDP": "89.70%",
    "Current Account": -2.1,
    "Population": 37.78
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an encoding error

did you try this

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{country}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```